# Multiple errors in C program

Tags: c

I have to make a program that has to ask the user for 2 array's of 3x3 in C and then print the sum_matrix that contains the sum in each place.

I also have to divide it in 3 functions, I've done it but it seems full of errors and I can't really get it to work.

PS: `righe` means lines, `colonne` columns, `inserisci` insert, `somma` sum , `stampa` print.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void leggi_matrice(int MAT[][], int nRighe, int nColonne);
void somma(int MAT1[][N], int MAT2[][], int nRighe, int nColonne);
void stampa_matrice(int MAT[][], int dim, int nRighe, int nColonne);

int main ()
{
    int mat_somma[][];
    int mat1[][];
    int mat2[][];
    int nRighe = 3;
    int nColonne =3;

    leggi_matrice( mat1[][], nRighe, nColonne);
    leggi_matrice(mat2[][], nRighe, nColonne);
    void somma(mat1[][], mat2[][], nRighe, nColonne);
    void stampa_matrice(mat_somma[][], nRighe, nColonne);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


void leggi_matrice(int MAT[][], int nRighe, int nColonne)
{
     for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++);
     for (j=0 ; j<nColonne ; j ++);
     {
         printf("Inserisci elemento");
         scanf("%d", & MAT[i][j]);
     }
}


void somma(int MAT1[][], int MAT2[][], int nRighe, int nColonne);
{
     int mat_somma[][];
     for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++);
     for (j=0 ; j<nColonne ; j ++);
     {
         mat_somma[i][j] = MAT1[i][j] + MAT2[i][j];
     }
}


void stampa_matrice(int MAT[][], int dim, int nRighe, int nColonne)
{
     int mat_somma[][];
     for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++);
     for (j=0 ; j<nColonne ; j ++);
     {
         printf ("%3d",mat_somma[i][j];
     }
}
```

Comment: Does this compile? I don't see where i and j are defined.

Comment: **NEVER** say that your program has errors without posting what the errors are here.

Comment: Ok Abelenky, sorry i'm new here, gonna work on that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, you **must** declare the size of your arrays:

**Bad**

```
int mat_somma[][];   
int mat1[][];
int mat2[][];
```

**Good**

```
int mat_somma[3][3];   
int mat1[3][3];
int mat2[3][3];
```

---

When making a function that receives an array, you must specify the inner-most dimension of your array.
In your case, I recommend specifying both dimensions of the array:

**Bad**

```
void leggi_matrice(int MAT[][], int nRighe, int nColonne)
```

**Good**

```
void leggi_matrice(int MAT[3][3], int nRighe, int nColonne)
```

---

When calling a function with an array, do NOT use brackets:

**Bad**

```
leggi_matrice( mat1[][], nRighe, nColonne);
```

**Good**

```
leggi_matrice( mat1, nRighe, nColonne);
```

---

When calling a function without a return value, do **NOT** put a `void` in front of it:

**Bad**

```
void somma(mat1, mat2, nRighe, nColonne);
```

**Good**

```
somma(mat1, mat2, nRighe, nColonne);
```

---

Declare your variables before you use them:

**Bad**

```
void leggi_matrice(int MAT[3][3], int nRighe, int nColonne)
{
    for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++)
    {
```

**Good**

```
void leggi_matrice(int MAT[3][3], int nRighe, int nColonne)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++)
    {
```

---

***After all this (and a few other trivial errors), your code should be like:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void leggi_matrice(int MAT[3][3], int nRighe, int nColonne);
void somma(int MAT1[3][3], int MAT2[3][3], int nRighe, int nColonne);
void stampa_matrice(int MAT[3][3], int nRighe, int nColonne);

int main ()
{
    int mat_somma[3][3];
    int mat1[3][3];
    int mat2[3][3];
    int nRighe = 3;
    int nColonne =3;

    leggi_matrice( mat1, nRighe, nColonne);
    leggi_matrice(mat2, nRighe, nColonne);
    somma(mat1, mat2, nRighe, nColonne);
    stampa_matrice(mat_somma, nRighe, nColonne);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


void leggi_matrice(int MAT[3][3], int nRighe, int nColonne)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++)
    {
        for (j=0 ; j<nColonne ; j ++)
        {
            printf("Inserisci elemento");
            scanf("%d", & MAT[i][j]);
        }
   }
}


void somma(int MAT1[3][3], int MAT2[3][3], int nRighe, int nColonne)
{
    int i;
    int j;
     int mat_somma[3][3];
     for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++)
     {
        for (j=0 ; j<nColonne ; j ++)
        {
            mat_somma[i][j] = MAT1[i][j] + MAT2[i][j];
        }
     }
}


void stampa_matrice(int MAT[3][3], int nRighe, int nColonne)
{
     int mat_somma[3][3];
     int i;
     int j;
     for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++)
     {
        for (j=0 ; j<nColonne ; j ++)
        {
            printf ("%3d",mat_somma[i][j]);
        }
     }
}
```

***Note to NitPickers***:
This isn't perfect C by a long-stretch.   But I'm not going to lecture him on pointers, style, structure, etc.  This helps a student along the path; this is not the destination.

Comment: Hey Abelenky! Thank you really much for the response, understood everything! There is just something, even if the last code you posted it doesn't print the last bidimensional array containing the sum, why isn't it printing? It gives random numbers :/

Comment: Are you able to tell me why isn't it printing the values that theoretically should be inside mat_somma?

Comment: Because in `somma()`, you're storing values in a local array and discarding them at the end of the function, and then in `stampa_matrice()` you're printing out the values from a local array which you've never initialized. You never update the `mat_somma[][]` in your `main()` function during `somma()`, so you pass an uninitialized array to `stampa_matrice()`, and then proceed to not even use it - you pass `MAT` but you print out a local uninitialized array called `mat_somma`. If you unexpectedly get random numbers, uninitialized variables are almost always to blame.

Comment: Thank you Paul, understood! I've managed to make it work by declaring mat_somma as global! Thank you both!

Answer (score 4):

```
for (i = 0; i < nRighe; i++);    
for (j = 0; j < nColonne; j++);
{
    printf ("%3d", mat_somma[i][j];
}
```

- You are ending a `for` loop with a `;` and in the local scope, these `{}`, you'll get undeclared variables that are being used: `i` and `j`.
- You need to define the data types of `i` and `j` in the `for` statement.
- And as Paul Griffiths mentioned, there is a missing parenthesis at the end of your `printf()` function.

I think you meant to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nRighe; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < nColonne; j++)
    {
        printf ("%3d", mat_somma[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Or the shorthand version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nRighe; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < nColonne; j++)
        printf ("%3d", mat_somma[i][j]);
```

Comment: Don't forget the missing paren on the `printf()` call.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Hawkeyes, thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a `;` everywhere after your `for` loops.

```
for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++);
```

is wrong. Change it like this.

```
for (i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++)
```

Because of this error you are not able to read in values and output them.

Also, define `i` and `j` before trying to use them. It will give you a compilation error. Try to understand what it means.

If you are using `C99` you can declare them inside the loop like this:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<nRighe ; i ++)
```

Otherwise declare them at the top of your function.